# Multiple tables in model are causing bizarre problems in C# program

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, data-binding

I created a database with several tables to be used for several things. The goal is to have a dynamic menu say called "Links" that view various network paths, or web pages, or whatever... Also they are bound so some combobox to be used to run some DOS commands such as ping, tracert.. etc

The program is far from finished, and a lot of functions are not done yet. But so far the database is local (for now) using a "Service based Database" and added the model "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".

The code I use to bind the combobox:

```
public List<Doscommand> DSC { get; set; }

private void bindcombo()
{
    Database1Entities dc = new Database1Entities();
    var item = dc.Doscommands.ToList();
    DSC = item;
    DataContext = DSC;
}
```

The problem is very strange. If the model ONLY has the `Doscommands` everything works just fine. But as soon as the model is updated with other tables, I get something like:

```
private void Exit_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

> Application does not contain a definition for 'Current'

and: output is showing:

> Error CS0263: Partial declarations of 'App' must not specify different base classes

The App.XAML is blank...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Hdtoolbox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

If I delete the other tables, we're back to no errors.

Should I be creating separate databases for each table? Or is the model wrong?

The config is shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a custom type called `Application` defined in the `Hdtoolbox` namespace.

You could try to use fully qualified type name of the `System.Windows.Application` class like this:

```
private void Exit_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

---

```
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
{
}
```

Comment: Wow.... there are no words. (there was a table called "application") I should have caught that....